# How to test or stub Sidekiq::Batch in RSPEC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, sidekiq, rspec-sidekiq

How to test or stub **Sidekiq::Batch** in **RSPEC** ?

Please see got **error** in code below.

## rails_helper

```
  require 'spec_helper'
  require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
  # Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
  abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'sidekiq/testing'
  Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
```

## Worker to be tested...

```
class TestWorker
    def perform(id)
        batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
        batch.description = "Sample"
        batch.on(:complete, TestWorker, 'id' => 123, 'last_checked' => Time.now)
        # =>  *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `on' for #<Batch:0x007fd8b728a1d0>

        batch.jobs do # => NoMethodError: undefined method `jobs' for #<Batch:0x007f936c9ebf68>
          Sidekiq::Client.push({
             'class' => TestWorker,
             'queue' => q,
             'args'  => [id, batch.bid, 1, Time.now]
          })
        end
    end
end

class TestWorkerCallbacks
  def complete(status, options)
    #simple record update here
  end
end
```

## spec/workers/test_worker_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TestWorker, type: :worker do
  context "Sidekiq Worker" do
    it "should respond to #perform" do
      expect(TestWorker.new).to respond_to(:perform)
    end

    describe "perform" do
      before do
        Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all
      end

      it "updates order records" do
        expect(TestWorker.jobs.size).to eq(0)
        TestWorker.perform_async(123)
        TestWorker.drain
        expect(TestWorker.jobs.size).to eq(1)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: have you tried using a `double` object?

Comment: @emaillenin not yet, can you please show some ex. code

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing#testing-batches

Comment: @emaillenin i tried that but no success, getting some undefined methods like, *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `on' for #<Batch:0x007fdd9e1d8de0> ....

Comment: as well as undefined method `jobs' => batch.jobs do

Comment: Do you mind to provide your test code @aldrien.h?